# Why my Query is returning null sometimes?

Tags: soql

I am querying for a particular user in my class(without sharing),it is returning null sometimes.User is available and he is the system administrator.
What might be the reason ? Am i missing anything ? 
Here is my Query  [Select id from user where FirstName = 'Vipul' and lastname = 'Sama' and profile.name = 'System Administrator' limit 1].

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is it by any chance not returning anything, in test code ?

Comment: I think if some users in the China access this functionality  its returning null.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of translation from endlish to chinees. You should take better ID and not a hrdcoded Name.

Here is some info for you: [Profile Name changes based on user language](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Profile-Name-changes-based-on-user-language/td-p/292085)

Comment: But why the code is getting effected by the language change,it runs in system mode right ?